# AJAX requests, 3 works the 4th one does not reach the PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm doing cascaded selects (4 of them) all the data is in a database. In order to fill the them i use sql queries depending on what was selected in the previous select. To communicate between the select and the next query i use AJAX requests which looks like that :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("select#select_theme").change(function(){
        var theme = $("select#select_theme option:selected").attr('value');

        $.ajax({
            type:"GET",
            url:"formation.php",
            data:"theme="+theme,
            async : true,
            success: function(html){
                $("#div-formation").html(html);
            }
        }); 
    });
});
```

This one works perfectly.
However for my last query i need 2 parameters (from select 2 and 3), so i did 2 requests for the select number 2 (one for select 3 and one for select 4) and although the AJAX requests are still the same the last one is not received by the .php page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("select#select_formation").change(function(){
        var nom_formation = $("select#select_formation option:selected").attr('value');

        $.ajax({
            type:"GET",
            url:"niveau.php",
            data:"nom_formation="+nom_formation,
            success: function(html){
                $("#div-niveau").html(html);
            }
        }); 
    });
});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("select#select_formation").change(function(){
        var formation = $("select#select_formation option:selected").attr('value');

        $.ajax({
            type:"GET",
            url:"version.php",
            data:"formation="+formation,
            success: function(html2){
                alert(formation);
            },
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

The second one is not received in php but the alert shows the proper value.

The error is : Notice: Undefined index: formation in C:\wamp\www\pluginDevis\version.php on line 5

I have tried different syntaxes for the data field but nothing seems to be working.

EDIT: the line 5 in the php is:

```
$formation = $_GET['formation'];
```

as it is for every other .php pages that works perfectly

[what it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/93oPQ.png)

---

#### Solved

I had it working by sending the 2 informations for the query in a single ajax request in other file

Comment: When second one is showing notice error it means your ajax `request` is striking `version.php` but there may be some problem with your code in version.php

Comment: The error itself saying there is problem in version.php file. Check your `version.php` file

Comment: well even if i only want to echo it, the error is the same

Comment: Try to display get array `print_r[$_GET];`. You will see whether there is any parameters set or not. Why you are not using `POST` method? `POST` is safe than `GET`.

Comment: that's the problem there is nothing in $_GET beside the other AJAX request that works fine, but the final one is not

Comment: show your php code (version.php), it might help

Comment: It may not help, as you say `formation` appears to alert correctly, but can you try combining the last 2 functions into one to ensure they aren't conflicting with each other. They are listening to the same event and using the same value, so it is more efficient anyway. I would also format the ajax `data` property as `data: {formation: formation}` so that jquery can URL-encode the value correctly.

Comment: well i tried to do the 2 requests inside the same function and to format the ajax the way you said but the php still doesn't receive "formation" i added a screenshot of the page and the php

Comment: One thing is in your code, you have two ajax call on `select_formation` change. First finish your call to `"niveau.php"` and in success of this file call make another ajax request to `version.php`. May be this helps

Comment: good idea, just tried it but same result :<

Comment: Before ajax call make sure you have value in `formation` by alert or console.

Comment: well it has to be since the value is used for a previous ajax request and it works

Comment: Instead of "has to be" make it sure

Comment: I think in your second Ajax call you are not honoring the returned value, which is **html2**. And the variable **formation** may always have the same contents from an earlier assignment.

Comment: Are 'cascaded selects' the same as 'dependent drop downs'

Answer (score 2):

Try changing your `data` parameter to be an object, e.g:

```
$.ajax({
    type:"GET",
    url:"version.php",
    data: {
        'formation': formation
    }
    ...
});
```

Also, you can quickly get the value using `.val()`, rather than `.attr('value')`. It's also better practice to use `.on('change')`, rather than `.change`, as a lot of these methods have been deprecated in later versions of jQuery.

If this doesn't help, check the network tab in chrome / firefox's inspector to see how your data is being submitted.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for the jquery tips, unfortunately changing the format of data doesn't work,

Comment: Have you looked at the network inspector to see if the issue is with how your data is being sent, or how the PHP is processing it?

Comment: it shows that the data is being sent but it seems to be override once i fill the third select, a fix would be to send the 2 needed data inside the same ajax request

Comment: Yes you have 2 event listeners on the same form input, getting the same value. What is being overridden, surely they would both be the same value?

Comment: managed to make it work, doing a single request for the 2 values in another file through an hidden input, thanks for suggesting to use the inspector it really helped :)